# how to extend main partition with gparted live cd

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I booted with gparted and it shows my main partition and an extended, wiht linux-swap inside(I do not know what this is) and I have about 17.00 GB of free space on a new partition but I cant seem to merge. When I click on the main partition and put resize it does not give me any options to merge, resize, etc.

[image]

**update**

[image]

Comment: Try to copy the swap partition, and pasting it right to the unailocated space. the deleting the old swap

Comment: I get 510 mb of unallocated space in the middle where the original dev/sda5 used to be and cant expand sda1. Is there anyway to bring those next to each other...

Comment: ok thanks I got it now, I had to play around with resize and move to get the unallocated right next to sda1

Comment: See also [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to delete the partition (New Partition #1) 
Then you will be able to resize sda1

Comment: Just leave the swap partition.

Comment: I deleted it and I have 17gb of unallocated space, but I still cannot resize sda1..

Comment: Did you also press apply after deleting it?

Comment: check update on original post